# Is a redirect from a third-party site bad?

Tags: 301-redirect, links, backlinks

I'm doing backlink cleanup for a client, and came across a page with a suspicious-looking redirect to their site.

The site is relevant to the content of my client's site, and linking domain's DA isn't as low as I would expect of a spammy site (16). That being said, I thought redirects were only to be used in cases of migrations or the deletion of internal pages. Here is the link:

http://www.digestive-science.com/gb/Enema-enema-equipment_aHR0cDovL3d3dy5vcHRpbWFsaGVhbHRobmV0d29yay5jb20vQ29sb24tQ2xlYW5zZS1FbmVtYS1FcXVpcG1lbnQtYW5kLUFjY2Vzc29yaWVzLXMvNC5odG0,_c9a

I noted that no referral traffic has come from the site, at least within the past year.

Should I request the webmaster remove that redirect, or leave it be?

Comment: A "redirect from a third-party site" isn't necessarily bad. I think your question is really... "is _this_ redirect bad?". It looks like it could be an affiliate link?! However, I think this might be your call... the link is relevant and adds value to the content (you say it is)? Is the affiliation disclosed (if there is an affiliation)? (Must admit that intermediary site looks very spam-like to me - popup alert when you try to leave; yuk!)

Comment: Generally, redirecting from one site to another should not be bad, however, it was used by spammers in the past. Even if it was totally innocent, I would think twice and prefer a link.

Comment: @w3d Thanks for your input! I agree that the site looks pretty spammy. Their DA of 16 throws me, but everything else points to a disreputable site to me. My client does not recall any affiliate relationship, so I will seek removal. Thanks again!

Comment: @closetnoc Great point about preferring a link. I agree completely. Thanks for your input!